# How to get previous selection of dropdown value when I click button?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

How to get previous selection of dropdown value when I click button. I refer below coding

```
    $(".addToButton").live('click', function (e) {
          var sel = $(this).prevAll(".addToList:first"),
          val = sel.val(),
          text = sel.find(':selected').text();    
    });
```

But it is not working. How should I get previous selection of dropdown value when I click button?

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated - try using `.on()`. And by previous, do you mean the previous selection the user has made, or the previous item on the list that the user has selected?

Comment: previous selection,that means the user selection what ever it is

Answer (score 3):

You cannot ask a control for a previous property value. If you need to remember it, you need to store it in a variable somewhere explicitly.

What you can do, is create a stack and then push the new value of the dropdownbox every time it changes.

Answer (score 0):

**Try Following code:**

```
    (function () {
            var prevVal;

            $("select").focus(function () {
                // For storing current value on focus and on change
                prevVal = this.value;
            }).change(function() {



                // Get new value in previous varible storage
                prevVal= this.value;
            });
          $("btnGet").click(function(){
 alert("This is previous value: "+prevVal);
});

        })();
```

Hope its helpful.

Comment: This for dropdown change event.but i want button click event.

Comment: Then just use the `.click()` function to set the prevVal value. @Freelancer is doing a proof-of-concept demo, not sure why it's so hard to adapt his code for your own use.

Comment: i was try to click event also.but it's not working.it returns value like undefined

Comment: @user2235898 declare var prevVal globally and then see the results.